# How can I know that a full node has finished the initial synchronization process?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, synchronization, full-node

I run a full bitcoin node. I launched it several days ago and it has consumed around 300 GB of traffic already which implies that it is about to finish the initial syncronization process.

Except for that implicit sign, is there a more reliable and concrete way of determinining whether or not a full node has finished the initial syncronization process? Is there a special RPC API call that would return "true" for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check three factors in the `getblockchaininfo` RPC call:

The result contains a count of the blocks in your chain, and the headers your node has received from peers. For a fully synchronized node, the number of blocks equals the number of headers.

Additionally, there is an `initialblockdownload` boolean in the response, which will be set to false once the node has caught up with the main chain.

Comment: is it normal that it's taken several days to syncronize a full node?

Comment: Yes it can take few days